# DB2 Z/OS - Revalidate UDF and Stored Procedure

Tags: db2, db2-zos

On DB2 AIX I can use the SYSPROC.ADMIN_REVALIDATE_DB_OBJECTS stored procedure to revalidate all Stored Procedures and Functions defined in my schema.

How can I do the same thing on DB2 z/OS (v.12)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

REGENERATE automatically rebinds, at the local server, the package for the SQL control statements for the procedure and rebinds the package for the SQL statements that are included in the procedure body. If a remote bind is also needed, the BIND PACKAGE COPY command must be explicitly done for all of the remote servers.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SCHEMA.NAME_SP REGENERATE ACTIVE VERSION;
```

For the moment I have not found anything that automatically revalidates/regenerates all Stored/UDFs of a Schema.